# force router to use proxy server / VPN

Tags: router, vpn, proxy

I have router that supports static and dynamic routing.

Is it possible to make router to use a proxy server/VPN with static IP? So every PC in the network can connect to blocked sites.

For example I will hire a proxy or VPN server. And, set a static routing table to send all traffic to the VPN.

Comment: Does your router support [DD-WRT](http://dd-wrt.com/site/index)

Comment: @Ramhound no, unfortunately

Comment: Then what you want isn't possible.  You can configure your OS and most mobile devices to use a VPN though with relative ease.

Comment: Are you sure it is not possible? :(

Comment: The router is linux based and I can open a busybox terminal. Do this have a use to us?

Comment: @Ramhound That is completely false, there are many other routers capable of doing this, plus the question clearly states that both static and dynamic routes can be added, which for many VPNs (most notably net-to-net ones) is all you need. However, to answer this question, we need to know what type of VPN you want to set up, as the way to do it can vary wildly -- including "not possible" for some of them. Any VPN that implements a simple SOCKS proxy, however, is easily done with just a static route.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is, as correctly pointed out by Kromey, *it depends*. It depends exactly on your router, and on the kind of VPN you wish to access.

However, I can suggest a solution that will *certainly* work, if you grant me the permission to try and fullfill your aim at large, instead of focusing on the answer to your exact question.

All you need to do is to buy a small pc (how small, in a second), use it as a gateway to the VPN, and then use this small pc, instead of your router, as **the** router on your network.

Now for the details:

1. the pc can be really small. To this aim, I use second-hand pcs bought on e-bay for 200$. But you can do even better, if you use a Raspberry Pi, which you can obtain for less than 40$.
2. It is easiest to do it in Linux (Raspian, for the Raspberry, is the simplest choice). In Linux, after setting up the VPN that connects this new pc to the VPN server, all you need to do is to use these two commands as root:

   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
3. In order to instruct the devices in your LAN to use this new pc as the new router, all you have to do is to change the default router IP address (details on how to do this depend on device, but basically it can be done for anything, pcs, printers, TVs, Blu-Ray players, you name it) to that of this new pc.

One of the advantages of this is that you can simultaneously have devices on the VPN or off it, and, for intance, you may use on your pc the VPN when you want to get around censorship, but use the normal router (which will be a bit faster) when you do not need to do that.

Comment: step 1 and 2 is ok. lets say i have set up a vpn outside the LAN with static IP. how can I forward all connections to this VPN. Note: i can use routers' busybox terminal as root.